# add one second to the specific times in r

Tags: r

Could you please tell me that how to add a single second to the datetimes which are ended from __:59?

i.e. from this:

```
              dateTime rain_mm
1  2012-12-01 00:00:00     1.0
2  2012-12-01 00:06:00     0.0
3  2012-12-01 00:11:59     0.0
4  2012-12-01 00:17:59     0.0
5  2012-12-01 00:24:00     0.2
6  2012-12-01 00:30:00     0.0
7  2012-12-01 00:36:00     1.0
8  2012-12-01 00:42:00     0.0
9  2012-12-01 00:48:00     0.8
10 2012-12-01 00:53:59     0.2
```

to:

```
              dateTime rain_mm
1  2012-12-01 00:00:00     1.0
2  2012-12-01 00:06:00     0.0
3  2012-12-01 00:12:00     0.0
4  2012-12-01 00:18:00     0.0
5  2012-12-01 00:24:00     0.2
6  2012-12-01 00:30:00     0.0
7  2012-12-01 00:36:00     1.0
8  2012-12-01 00:42:00     0.0
9  2012-12-01 00:48:00     0.8
10 2012-12-01 00:54:00     0.2
```

Any help please?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can check `as.integer(format(x, "%S") == "59")` which when converted into integer will become either `1` or `0` which you can conveniently add to the `x` since `POSIXct` is a measure of seconds (typically from 1970-01-01:00:00:00 or, in some cases, arbitrary origin).

```
x = structure(c(1354342319, 1354343040), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
x
#[1] "2012-12-01 00:11:59 CST" "2012-12-01 00:24:00 CST"
x + as.integer(format(x, "%S") == "59")
#[1] "2012-12-01 00:12:00 CST" "2012-12-01 00:24:00 CST"
```

Comment: `POSIXct` is always a measure of seconds since 1970-01-01:00:00:00, though you can input from an arbitrary origin in `as.POSIXct`